# Are big checks (dimensions, not money) valid?

Tags: united-states, check

You've probably seen the really big checks given to winners of monetary prizes. Are these checks valid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's assume the oversized checks aren't  valid. That means the people giving you the prize gives you a standard check after they take the picture.

The oversized checks are a prop. They are for PR purposes.

If you look at thr pictures the big checks are missing the name of a bank. They also don't include an account number. Your bank won't cash them or accept them for deposit.

Answer (score 6):

In the mid 80’s, I wrote a check to the IRS and sent it along with my tax form.

The check was hand written on a white msn’s dress shirt. As I recall, the IRS cashed it, and the bank charged me $5 or $10 for using a non-standard check.

Answer (score 3):

The ones you are referring to probably aren't. But there is no reason an oversized check couldn't be valid as long as it had all the proper information on it and the bank can verify that the owner of the account intended to transfer money to you.

Answer (score 1):

Banks are no longer expected  to accept checks that can not be scanned by their standard machines. This changed in the last few decades. See [my other answer today](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/152512).